# Is a "product" necessarily sellable?

Tags: single-word-requests

A definition of "product" is goods and services which are designed to be sold.

But how about a system which is not directly sold, but is designed to deliver services? E.g. an Information System which then supplies services to customers. There may be many such systems, each offering different ranges of services.

Sample sentence: "We have implemented several "products" to offer on-premises cloud services to internal customers."

I have looked in online dictionaries, but can't find this usage of "product".

Can we say that these systems are products? They have genuinely been "produced", but they themselves are not sold. It seems odd that a word about *creation* is defined only by how it's *bought*.

The word "system" or "information system" seem too general, and doesn't give the connotation of assembly or production.

And if we can't say these systems are products, is there a more accurate word or compound word or phrase, please?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You give a definition of *product* in the first sentence that directly contradicts it describing something that is not sellable. A product doesn't need to be sold; but if it isn't, then you can't use the specific definition you've provided. For example, one sense of [*product*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/product) is "**2  a (1)** : something produced." That definition includes sewage and other waste products that are never sold.

Comment: @Jason Blassford. Yes exactly my point - I have a sense that goes against what is a standard definition. The Merriam-Webster definition "something produced" carries on as "especially commodity", and I don't find myself convinced by this

Comment: Just because it says *especially*, that doesn't mean *exclusively*. It just means "the most common from among several." But, as I said, *waste* ***products*** uses a different meaning which is still common, even if not the most common relative to others. If you want a reference to something explicitly not sellable, look at [Oxford's definition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/product).

Comment: 1.1: "A substance produced during a natural, chemical, or manufacturing process. 'waste products' ." 2: "A thing or person that is the result of an action or process. 'her perpetual suntan was the product of a solarium' ."

Comment: But if you want to exclude any non-sellable sense from your use of the word, you can do that. However, it then becomes an internal definition that doesn't match how other people use the word.

Comment: As for the the sentence itself (which is awkward despite the correct use of the word): *"We freely offer many products to our on-premises customers."*

Comment: Note that I would turn all of these comments into an actual answer, but it's still not clear exactly what you're after—assurance that *products* doesn't always mean sellable, or, having convinced yourself that it does, an alternative word.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments - they help me to see that but synonym works better. I know "especially not exclusively" but it conveys a tone

Comment: You don't need to put product in quotes. You are in fact selling it on some basis. Even offering a free infrastructure platform for later applications to run on, you have a product. Isn't Google, as a free service to users, a product?

Comment: @Yosef Balkin A Google definition is offering = service or product. The definition I gave earlier product = good or service. The question is whether a platform which (1) is not intended to be sold but (2) supports services which are sold can be regarded as a product in either sense. Would you have to pay Goods and Services Tax on it? No

Answer (score 1):

> "We have implemented several "products" to offer on-premises cloud
>   services to internal customers."

In the sample sentence, 'implemented' seems out of place because it is being offered, not done.  That said,

"We have developed several applications/processes/storage models/options for on-premise cloud services to internal customers."

Comment: Thanks for these tries! This is only technology infrastructure, with no software development, so it's not really an application. It isn't a process. Technically, it's more than storage. And options is not right. It's something tangible which offers something intangible. The best word I can find is platform

Comment: design features/strategies, functionality enhancements.

Comment: yes i agree some synonym is best: we came up with: platform, solution, offering...

Comment: Sorry - new here

Comment: Reopened it sorry, as there is still continuing discussion in other comments which might lead somewhere

Comment: And these "products" are implemented - they have been made and are real. They are not being offered. This is bringing up another point which is that they are concrete instances, rather than something sitting in a catalogue

Comment: No prob with change. However, still have concerns with 'implemented' because it implies put into effect/enforced on user side. Is the Information System a 'software enhancement' that is available to users? Still trying to understand the angle you're after. Software add-on being offered?

Comment: Kind of analogy: suppose Coca-Cola manufactured ("implemented") their own vending machines. Would these be products?

Comment: Does this get closer or still miss the mark:  Application delivery services. https://avinetworks.com/glossary/application-delivery/    A service delivery platform (SDP)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_delivery_platform

Comment: Wow that's really good. Thanks so much. It started as a telecoms terms but as the article says it's grown from there. Guess because people need a term for this! It also uses the term platform, which I think is accurate. Unless someone comes up with a better term very soon, I'll go with this.

Comment: Here's a list of different platform types:  https://medium.com/platform-hunt/the-8-types-of-software-platforms-473c74f4536a

Comment: The general term is “solution”.